# Не подключаются файлы через namespace

Tags: php

В файле `/controllers/AddController.php` подключенный через `use` класс из другого файла.

```html
<?
use Models\categoryBild;
$category = new categoryBild;

class AddController{
    
    public function actionView(){
            
         $category = new categoryBild;       
    }
}
```

Сам подключённый файл `models/category.php`.

```html
<?
namespace Models;

class categoryBild{

    public function category(){

        $category = array('men','woman', 'el_acs');

        return $category;
    }
}
```

Но класс не подключается, `Uncaught Error: Class 'Models\categoryBild' not found in`

Что не так?

Comment: ну как минимум класс должен называться также как и файл, и с большой буквы

Comment: Покажите код require/include

Comment: @AntonKucenko с чего бы вдруг?

Comment: @rjhdby с чего вдруг класс должен называться так же как и файл?

Comment: @AntonKucenko именно. И почему с большой буквы?

Comment: user3127286 без `require/include` разве пространства имён не работают? Во фреймворках таких подключений нет, там всё через `use`, и всё работает. По поводу имени класса: это может быть рекомендацией, и условием для работы некоторых шаблонов, для интерпретатора это не имеет никакого значения.

Comment: Вас уже спрашивали - где автозагрузчик? Если вы используете какой-то известный фреймворк - укажите его __название__, тегом или в тексте вопроса. Во фреймворках все работает, потому что там есть собственный __автозагрузчик__, но вы об этом не знаете.

Comment: это не фреймворк. Автозагрузчика нет. Что такое  - не знаю.

Comment: И разбираться не хочу, да?

Comment: Если в этом дело - буду только рад. Прочёл документацию, кучу статей, пересмотрел видео, там всё просто: тут присвоил пространство - там вызвал, всё работает, только не у меня. Про автозагрузчик нигде ни слова.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.autoload.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Следует принять во внимание PSR стандарты и начинать класс с большой буквы при 
 использовании вызова вашего класса categoryBild c помощью
[composer autoload](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload)

Или использовать собственную реализацию автозагрузки. 
[Автоматическая загрузка классов](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.autoload.php)